# Как получить значение ячейки таблицы?

Tags: google-apps-script

Правильно ли, что getCell возвращает значение ячейки таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет.

[getCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)) возвращает ссылку на объект класса [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) со всеми его свойствами.

Чтобы получить значение, необходимо вызвать один из методов этого класса

```
// getValue()
var value = sheet.getCell(1, 1).getValue();

// getDisplayValue()
var value = sheet.getCell(1, 1).getDisplayValue();
```